# Designing the bridge between REST layer to service layer

Tags: design, architecture, rest

I am working on a project and would like to expose some REST services. The technologies used are RestEasy, EJB and JPA/Hibernate. I have structured my app so that there is a clear delimitation between the service layer and model layer. A typical service that retrieves data from the database have a signature like this: `getWhateverList(idForWhichTheListWillBeRetrieved, start)` - so pretty basic.

What I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around is how to bring together the stiffness of the service layer with the flexibility of the REST layer. Say for example that I would like a typical GET method producing a JSON array support operations like:

- filtering - use a query param to get, for example items that have a property of type date greater/lower than the param that I provide
- sorting - REST API should support asc or desc
- limiting the fields that are returned from the GET operation

How would one go about designing this?

Comment: if you're using Spring you should check out Spring Data REST.  There are some decisions made for you in that space, around the GET,PUT, DEL .. etc with some nice examples.

Comment: sorry for the incredible late response, had a busy period. i did look into spring's solution and it provided some useful pointers for me to integrate in my application. @Erik thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

> - filtering - use a query param to get, for example items that have a
>   property of type date greater/lower than the param that I provide

For that you need a query language. You can use any existing query language as long as you describe it with metadata in your links. So your clients and server can have a common contract which is described by that metadata. For example `GET /users?q="statement using a standard query language"`.

You can describe simple queries using [URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570). For example `GET /users?firstName={firstName}`

> - sorting - rest api should support asc or desc

You can use the same links described above with additional query params. For example `GET /users?sortBy="name"&direction="asc"`.

> - limiting the fields that are returned from the GET operation

You can use the same links described above with additional query params. For example `GET /users?fields="firstName,secondName,age"`.

note: According to the uniform interface / HATEOAS constraint you have to send links to your clients. According to the uniform interface / self-descriptive messages constraint, these links have to contain meta-data (for example link relation) about what they are. So the clients can check that meta-data and chose the proper link to reach their goal.